# I have to click twice to make the div visible. How to solve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var divs = ["userMenu", "submenu"];
var visibleDivId = null;

function toggleVisibility(divId) {
    if (visibleDivId == divId) {
        visibleDivId = null;
    } else {
        visibleDivId = divId;
    }
    hideNonVisibleDivs();
}

function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
    var i, divId, div;
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    {
        divId = divs[i];
        div = "#" + document.getElementById(divId).id;
        if (visibleDivId == divId) 
            $(div).fadeIn();
        else 
            $(div).fadeOut();
    }
}
```

The first time it's working just fine. But when I try to open the same div after clicking an a-element which will close the div I have to click it twice. I see why, the first time I click the div, visisbleDivId is the same as divId, so visibleDivId will be set null. Second click, it will fadeOut since it's no longer the same as divId.

I see what's going wrong, but I have no clue how to solve it.

Comment: You can store elements or JQuery objects in variables instead of just their ids. That might make things easier for you.

Comment: please give the complete code or js fiddle

Comment: WTF is with this line: `div = "#" + document.getElementById(divId).id;` ...are you literally using the id string to call getElementById solely for the purpose of then getting the id string?

Comment: @hjpotter92: i think he call on a div : onclick="toggleVisibility(this.id)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that extra function.   Because you store which div is the visible one in "visibleDivId", you only need to hide that one and not loop through the other divs.

```
var divs = ["userMenu", "submenu"];
var visibleDivId = null;

function toggleVisibility(divId) {
    if (visibleDivId == divId) {
        $(visibleDivId).fadeOut();
        visibleDivId = null;
    } else {
        if (visibleDivId) {
            $(visibleDivId).fadeOut();
        }
        visibleDivId = divId;
        $(visibleDivId).fadeIn();
    }
}
```

Comment: Same as Ilyas Mimouni, it's never able to close itself after a second click since visibleDivId is the same as divId